# Import modules into next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, npm-link

Actually i have a project which i need to include in Next JS as a module. So basically i am trying to use it via `npm link`, I am successfully able to add that module into my next JS repo as a component. But it is breaking because of webpack loaders. Should i need to add all the loaders necessary in next JS? what is better way to achieve this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @felixmosh Please take a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Next.js doesn't compiles dependencies located at `node_modules`.

You should use [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) in order to instruct it to compile specific libs.

```js
// next.config.js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['somemodule', 'and-another']);

module.exports = withTM({
  ...regular next config
});
```

Comment: getting below error after adding this. ```Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.tsx. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).```

Comment: you can't import css files without `.module.css` suffix from outside of `_app`, if your lib does that, and you use `css modules` just add the suffix

Comment: Hey @felixmosh `Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.` Although there is no mix of import's in any on the component.

Comment: Looks like one of your imports is returning an undefined, and you pass it to react as a component

Comment: Is there a better way to debug this ? Cause you know there are lot of files in other module that i imported to next JS.

Comment: Just from the error code, this error is React related error... so focus on components

Comment: `const init = (config, IDselector) => {     ReactDOM.render(         <Provider store={configureStore()}>             <App config={config} />         </Provider>,     document.getElementById(IDselector)); };  export default init(null, 'root');` This is the component which gets imported at next JS using npm link. So i think this is the issue. So basically i am just rendering here and not returning anyhting. That is the error i suppose. @felixmosh

Answer (score 1):

With the new update of Next, js supports ES Modules and URL Imports.

> Starting with Next.js 11.1, we added experimental support for ES modules being prioritized over CommonJS modules. In Next.js 12, this is now the default. Importing NPM modules that only provide CommonJS is still supported.

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#es-modules-support-and-url-imports